# Stop Java Process if Running in Raspbian

Tags: java, command-line-interface, raspbian, application-shutdown

I want to make sure that a java process in Raspbian is stopped before launching a new instance of it.

My approach, until now, has been to try to create a one-line command to stop the process from the command line, as it is the easiest way to include this step in the GO continuos delivery tool. This far, I was able to come up with this *solution*, which effectively stops the process:

```
kill $(jps -m | grep NameOfTheMainClass | awk '{print $1}')
```

**But** the problem is that when the process was not started, the kill fails as it has no pid to signal. How could I fix that?

Comment: @SubOptimal The problem with java processes is that, from the OS perspective, they are all named "java", therefore I cannot `pidof NameOfTheMainClass`

Comment: Why don't you use `ps ax | grep NameOfTheMainClass` ?

Comment: Use a little bash script that checks if the thing runs before killing it like you do.

Comment: @SimonZambrovski `ps ax` shows itself in the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer a one-liner

```
JPID=$(jps -m | grep NameOfTheMainClass  | awk '{print $1}') && [ -z "$JPID" ] || kill $JPID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it conditional:

```
export MAIN_CLASSNAME=""

isRunning()
{
  PID=`ps ax | grep MAIN_CLASSNAME | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
  is_running="false"
  if [ ! -z "$PID" ]; then
    is_running="true"
  fi
  test "$is_running" = "true"
}

if isRunning; then
  kill $PID       
fi
```

Comment: Watch out with this. As I said, `ps ax` shows itself, you will end up killing the `ps` instead

Comment: `ps ax  | grep foo` will show `grep` not `ps ax`.
To avoid this, you usualy exlude the grep by adding:
`ps ax | grep MAIN_CLASSNAME | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`